# A holomorphic function satisfying $f(z)=f(iz)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $G\subset \mathbb{C}$ be open and define $\Omega = \{ z\in\mathbb{C}: z^4\in G \}.$ Assume that $f$ is analytic on $\Omega$ and satisfies $f(iz)=f(z)$ for all $z\in \Omega$. I would like to show that there exists an analytic function $g$ such that $f(z)=g(z^4)$ for all $z\in \Omega$.

The converse is clearly true as $(iz)^4=z^4$, but it doesn't seem to offer many clues as to how to prove the other and harder direction.

Letting $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ with $z=x+iy$, the constraint turns into $u(x,y)=u(-y,x)$ and $v(x,y)=v(-y,x)$ with of course $\Delta u=0$, $\Delta v=0$.

I had the idea of writing, for any $z_0\in \Omega$ and for some neighborhood of $z_0$, since $f$ is analytic, the following equality holds
$$f(z)=\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{a_k}{k!} (z-z_0)^k.$$
Thus,
$$0=f(z)-f(iz)= \sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{a_k}{k!} (z-z_0)^k(1-i^k)=\sum_{k\neq 0 \operatorname{mod} 4} \frac{b_k}{k!} (z-z_0)^k$$
for $b_k=a_k(1-i^k)$. At this point, I want to conclude that necessarily $b_k\equiv 0$ for all $k\neq 0 \operatorname{mod} 4$, and thus $a_k=0$ for all $k\neq 0 \operatorname{mod} 4$. Hence, we can write
$$f(z)=\sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{a_{4n}}{(4n)!} ((z-z_0)^4)^n=g((z-z_0)^4)$$
where
$$g(z)=\sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{a_{4n}}{(4n)!} z^n$$
is analytic since $f$ is, but $z_0$ is not necessarily zero.

Comment: Note that your formulas only work for $z_0=0$.

Comment: I would try to argue from $$f(z) = \frac14(f(z) + f(iz) + f(-z) + f(-iz)).$$

Answer (score 2):

You want $g(w) = f(w^{1/4})$.  Now $w^{1/4}$ is a multivalued function, but that doesn't matter because $f$ agrees on all four fourth roots of $w$.  For each $w \ne 0$, you can take a branch of the fourth root analytic in a neighbourhood of $w$, and this makes $g$ analytic in that neighbourhood of $w$.

We still need to show that $g$ is analytic at $w=0$ (if $0 \in G$).  But an isolated singularity in a neighbourhood of which the function is bounded is a removable singularity.